# What are Trace Elements in Heap Profile?

Tags: haskell

When profiling my Haskell program with the -hd flag, I see about 50K listed as "Trace Elements". What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are additional bands in the heap graph that would be too small to display, that is, each one only contributes “trace amounts” of size to the heap, like [trace chemical elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_element). You can adjust the threshold with the `-t` flag, documented in the [GHC User’s Guide §8.5. `hp2ps` – Rendering heap profiles to PostScript](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#cmdoption-hp2ps-t):

> `-t⟨float⟩`
>
> Normally trace elements which sum to a total of less than 1% of the profile are removed from the profile. The `-t` option allows this percentage to be modified (maximum 5%).
>
> `-t0` requests no trace elements to be removed from the profile, ensuring that all the data will be displayed.